# Annotate count of related related filtered objects

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-database, django-aggregation, django-annotate

I have these models:

```
class Shop(..):
    category = ForeignKey...

class Product(..):
    shop = ForeignKey...
    category = ForeignKey...
    is_active = BooleanField...

class Category(..):
    name = ...
```

I need to annotate the number of active products for each category.

Basically this:

```
for cat in Category.objects.all():
    count = Product.objects.filter(shop__category=cat)
```

I tried:

```
Category.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('shop__products'),filter=Q(shop__products__is_active=True))

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_active
```

This raises an error. Do you know how to annotate this?

Comment: What erro you have got?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_active

Comment: BTW, from your post, it is not clear how does the `Shop` and `Product` is related. IMHO, better to add the *"relevant, exact model specification"* in questions so that you will have a high chance of getting accurate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) should be argument of `Count` object:

```
Category.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('shop__products', filter=Q(shop__products__is_active=True)))
```